# Strange exception during maven install, but build getting sucess

Tags: java, maven, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

While doing the maven install some strange exception popping out

```
 [WARNING] Exception while updating local OBR: Unable to read repository xml: file:/home/.m2/repository/repository.xml
 org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to read repository xml: file:/home/.m2/repository/repository.xml
    at org.apache.felix.obrplugin.ObrUpdate.parseRepositoryXml(ObrUpdate.java:324)
    at org.apache.felix.obrplugin.ObrInstall.execute(ObrInstall.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@34d475c1) 
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(Unknown Source)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.PullParser.parseRepository(PullParser.java:43)
    at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.DataModelHelperImpl.repository(DataModelHelperImpl.java:147)
    at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.DataModelHelperImpl.repository(DataModelHelperImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.felix.obrplugin.ObrUpdate.parseRepositoryXml(ObrUpdate.java:316)
... 22 more
```

This is the exception I'm getting while giving `maven install`. It occurs for all projects. I'm compiling ***OSGI-BUNDLES*** with maven. Changing the `settings.xml` is also not helping. I can't deploy my bundles in Karaf due to this error. Seems `.m2/repository/repository.xml` is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Mojo Exception that occurs is due to the issue that some jar is not being downloaded properly during mvn install.

Try to delete your .m2 local repository and do a clean build again and see if you face the same problem again.

Also try to check the compatibility of Java verson with the Maven version you are using that can also cause an issue. dependency checking can also some time solve it as you may have forgotten to add the correct dependency in your pom.xml

Comment: I tried cleaning maven local repository but no help. Java version is also compatible with the maven version.Dependencies also correct one.Seems my **repository.xml** is empty.

Comment: did you try deleting local .m2 repository check this option also. before deleting just take a backup in case. only cleaning will not help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`[WARNING] Exception while updating local OBR: Unable to read repository xml: file:/home/.m2/repository/repository.xml`

On my machine this was because permissions on the `repository.xml` for my user were mysteriously removed. When i restored them, the error went away and everything behaved as expected.